# Chart.js remove the first vertical line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

Is there a way to remove the initial vertical line from the chart without removing the values?
[image: chart.js remove vertical line]

here is how my options look like:

```
scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                maxTicksLimit: 5,
                suggestedMax: maxValue
            }
        }],
        xAxes : [{
            categoryPercentage: 1.0,
            display : false, // set this to false to hide the labels under the bars
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            }
        }]
    },
```

Answer (score 14):

What you want to remove is probably the border of the chart. In Chart.js v2 I was able to remove this first vertical border by setting `drawBorder` to `false` for the grid line configuration:

```js
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                drawBorder: false
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

In Chart.js docs it is explained in https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration.

Comment: This is what worked for me. Thanks! PS: This documentation link doesn't work anymore.

The link that mention drawBorder now is:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html?q=drawborder

Answer (score 1):

Try using the chart option, `scaleLineColor`, and setting the color to have `0` opacity:

```js
new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, {
  scaleLineColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wb3kcunt/33/

If you are using chartjs `v2`, then the showBorder option in `scales.gridLines` should do the trick:

```js
options: {
  scales: {
    gridLines: {
      showBorder: false,
    }
  }
}
```

See docs: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales

Comment: Thanks, I'm using v2 and I tried that and it didn't work. 
Is the first solution only applicable to V1 ?